# understand "switch-profile" for Nexus 5k switches

Tags: cisco, switch, cisco-commands, cisco-nexus, cisco-nx-os

Am I correct that if there is no `switch-profile` configured for pair of Cisco Nexus 5k switches, then `conf sync` does not work regardless that CFS(Cisco Fabric Services) is enabled over management interfaces between this pair of switches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting up the configuration synchronization mode (`conf sync`) involves creating a switch profile (`switch-profile`). Cisco has a lot of documents regarding this, e.g. [Chapter: Configuring Switch Profiles](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/datacenter/nexus5000/sw/system_management/502_n1_1/b_Cisco_n5k_system_mgmt_cg_rel_502_n1_1/Cisco_n5k_system_mgmt_cg_rel_502_n1_1_chapter3.html):

> ## Prerequisites for Switch Profiles
>
> Switch profiles have the following prerequisites:
>
> - You must enable CFSoIP distribution over mgmt0 on both switches by    entering the cfs ipv4 distribute command.
> - You must configure a switch profile with the same name on both    peer-switches by entering the config sync and switch-profile
>     commands.
> - Configure each switch as peer switch by entering the sync-peers    destination command
>
> ## Configuration Guidelines and Limitations
>
> Switch profiles have the following configuration guidelines and limitations:
>
> - You can only enable configuration synchronization using the mgmt0    interface.
> - You must configure synchronized peers with the same switch profile    name.
> - Commands that are qualified for a switch profile configuration are    allowed to be configured in the configuration switch profile
>     (config-sync-sp) mode.
> - Supported switch profile commands relate to vPC commands. FCoE    commands are not supported.
> - One switch profile session can be in progress at a time. Attempts to    start another session will fail.
> - Supported command changes made from the configuration terminal mode    are blocked when a switch profile session is in progress. You should
>     not make unsupported command changes from the configuration terminal
>     mode when a switch profile session is in progress..
> - When you enter the commit command and a peer switch is reachable, the    configuration is applied to both peer switches or neither
>     switch. If    there is a commit failure, the commands remain in the
>     switch profile    buffer. You can then make necessary corrections and
>     try the commit    again.
> - Cisco recommends that you enable pre-provisioning for all    Gigabit-Ethernet Modules (GEMs) and Cisco Nexus Fabric Extender
>     modules whose interface configurations are synchronized using the
>     configuration synchronization feature. Follow these guidelines in
>     Cisco Nexus Fabric Extender A/A topologies where the Fabric Extenders 
>     might not be online on one switch and its configuration is changed
>     and synchronized on the other switch. In this scenario, if you do not 
>     enable pre-provisioning, a commit fails and the configuration is
>     rolled back on both switches.
>
> ## Configuring Switch Profiles
>
> You can create and configure a switch profile. Enter the
>   switch-profile *name* command in the configuration synchronization
>   mode (config-sync).
>
> **Before You Begin**
>
> You must create the switch profile with the same name on each switch
>   and the switches must configure each other as a peer. When
>   connectivity is established between switches with the same active
>   switch profile, the switch profiles are synchronized.
>
> **SUMMARY STEPS**
>
> 1. configuration terminal
> 2. cfs ipv4 distribute
> 3. config sync
> 4. switch-profile name
> 5. sync-peers destination IP-address
> 6. show switch-profile name status
> 7. exit
> 8. copy running-config startup-config